# What to say when interviewer introduce himself and pauses a little?

Tags: greetings

I've had an interview on Skype that interviewer introduced himself and paused a little long after. It was weird that I didn't know what to say as he already knew me. So he explained about the company and interview started.

How do you respond on Skype when someone introduce himself? Is it correct to say `Nice talking to you` or `I'm very pleased talking to you` or is there a better way to respond to the interviewer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about English _language_, and is better suited on [interpersonal.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's so nice we could meet."
"It's very nice to be speaking with you."

Comment: There's no way for you to resonably _prove_ this is the 'correct' answer, since such an answer doesn't exist.